# MFC: Creating horizontally or vertically oriented custom toolbar based on CControlBar

Tags: c++, mfc, docking

attempting for a vertically oriented *CControlBar*-derived custom toolbar. Presumably no results so far as it's always horizontal or always vertical or I don't actually know - too many parameters to get in sync, I'm affraid!

Here's what I've got so far:

```
// creating the CControlBar-derived toolbar
CMyCB cb; // CControlBar-derived toolbar
cb.Create(  AfxRegisterWndClass(0),
        NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,
        CRect(0,0,100,100),
        AfxGetMainWnd(),
        0
);
cb.SetBarStyle( cb.GetBarStyle() | CBRS_LEFT | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_GRIPPER );
cb.EnableDocking( CBRS_ORIENT_HORZ );

// in CFrameWnd-derived window constructor
this->EnableDocking( CBRS_ALIGN_ANY );
this->FloatControlBar( &cb, CPoint(100,100), CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT );
this->ShowControlBar( &cb, TRUE, FALSE );
```

Observing how *CControlBar::CalcFixedLayout* (overriden in *CMyCB*) is called by placing a breakpoint there, I can see it's *bHorz* argument (informing whether *cb* is a horizontal or vertical toolbar) takes on "2" for the first call, and "0" for the very subsequent second call.

What can I conclude from this? Is there a way how to create a custom toolbar that is consistently horizontal or consistently vertical? (at least as for the *bHorz* argument) Please see the parameters *CBRS_* * in the above snippet. Many thanks.

Tomas

Answer (score 0):

I never get a toolbar to align it to the left and right just with the settings an CreateEx call. No problem with Panes. Even debugging into the depth of the MFC code didn't show me the reason.

So here my simple solution.

m_wndHorzBar is the name of the bar you want to align to the left. I just used the wizard to create some sample code and I expect that you have a normal toolbar and a menu, so that you can see the context.

```
// Create it (just for simplicity no error checking) 
// CBR_LEFT seamed to be ignored 
m_wndHorzBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_LEFT | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC);

...

// Allow the normal bars to align anywhere
m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
// this bar should be aligned only in the left docking area
m_wndHorzBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT);

// Perform the initial docking
EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
DockPane(&m_wndMenuBar);
DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);
DockPane(&m_wndHorzBar);

// Now allow the bar to be docked anywhere by the user
m_wndHorzBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
```